# What do I have to do with jj in order to fix the operand type error for +: int and tuple?

Tags: python, operands

```
 >>> sum(jj)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    sum(jj)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
>>> jj
((2,), (2, 3))
```

Why does python throw that error? And, how do I fix it?

Comment: what do you want to do ?

Comment: @ashishsingh get the total sum of jj

Comment: You can take the sum of sums: `sum(map(sum, jj))`

Comment: Do you want `(4, 3)` or `7`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import itertools

jj = ((2,), (2, 3))

foo = sum(itertools.chain(*jj))
```

result is `7`.

Comment: Deeper nesting like `( (1,), (2, 0), (3, (1, 3, 5)) )` (two or more deep) fails.

Comment: @EricJin True, but he was not asking for that.

Answer (score 0):

Each item inside your tuple `jj` is itself a tuple, and you can't add the tuple `(2,)` to `0` (`sum()` starts with a value of 0, that you can change with a second argument).

You must sum each item in each tuple in `jj`.

```py
>>> jj = ((2,), (2, 3))
>>> jj
((2,), (2, 3))
>>> find_sum = lambda iterable: sum([sum(i) for i in iterable])
>>> find_sum(jj)
7
```

For a tuple of nested objects like `jj = [ (1,), (2, 0), (3, (1, 3, 5)) ]`, this will work:

```py
def find_total_sum(iterable):
    total = 0
    def find_sum(iterable):
        nonlocal total
        for item in iterable:
            if isinstance(item, int):
                total += item
            elif isinstance(item, (tuple, list)):
                find_sum(item)
    find_sum(iterable)
    return total

print(find_total_sum([ (1,), (2, 0), (3, (1, 3, 5)) ]))
```